# react native - when changing a property in state all other properties are then empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

hi this is my first question so please go easy. i am new to react native and i am failing to make the below code work:

```
const [posts, setPost] = useState(props.post);
const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
const onLikePress = async () => {
    setPost({likes: posts.items.likes + 1})
};
```

end goal of the above code is to increase the number of likes on a post, props are passed form home page and all works fine, but then tapping the like button it seems as if the post state is nulled and all fields become empty.

below is a screen shot from expo, before pressing the like icon all content from props shows fine.
[image: EXPO error]

any help in understanding why this happens is appreciated

EDIT:

thanks for the help here, its now working but im still a little confused, when i set the state as below everything i try errors.

```
const [posts, setPost] = useState(props.post);
```

but if i change this line to be

```
const [posts, setPost] = useState(props.post.item);
```

i am able to update the likes with

```
setPost({...posts, likes:posts.likes+1})
```

can any one help me understand why props.posts is passed with item and data contained in item, is this a quirk of using flat list

Comment: You are overwriting posts state with a new obj, could you provide a data structure example of the posts state?

Comment: hi thanks for the response,the props are passed form a flat list and are as follows, index: 0
item:
comments: []
description: " "this is my bug""
likes: 19
shares: 14
songImage: " """
videoUri: "https://d8vywknz0hvjw.cloudfront.net/fitenium-media-prod/videos/45fee890-a74f-11ea-8725-311975ea9616/proccessed_720.mp4"
__v: 0
_id: "602e37930d86848198e599cc"

Comment: im new to this please let me know if you would like it in a better formatt

Comment: its okey, if i correctly understand your data posts:[...anyProperty, likes:Integer] structure this should work:  setPost(posts.map(post=> {return{...post, likes:post.likes+1}})

Comment: hi this gives type error posts.map is not a function

Comment: it means that posts are not an array just a plain obj {},  If it is you should try this setPost({...posts, likes:posts.likes+1})

Answer (score 1):

You have overwritten state. In that case, you can try the following code:

```
setPosts({...posts,"likes": posts.items.likes + 1});
```

For further information, you can refer https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-meadow-9dkj3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason mentioned in the comments you are overwriting the state variable entirely.
Try using the following syntax instead:

```
var person={name:"my name","age":21}
setPerson({...person,"birth":1999});
```

Expected result for the above is: person={name:"my name","age":21,"birth":1999}

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, im not sure i understand here, are you saying i need to create a new object of my props that i set with useState(props.post) but leave out the property i want to update and then add that property in the setPosts?  im sure i am incredibly wrong here

Comment: the '...' is called the spread operator. It creates a new object for you.
For your specific use case you can use {...post, "like" : value} and it should work as expected